# How can I access elements in v-for

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a `v-for` loop iterating over an array called `projects`. I have another array called `selectedProjects`. When a `project` element is clicked, I'd like to add a class called `selected` to that specific element, as well as add the `project.id` property of that index to `selectedProjects`. Maybe I'm going about the whole problem wrong, is there a "vue" way to achieve this?

```
<!-- The template -->
<div v-for="project in projects" class="project" @click="">
    <p><i class="fa fa-folder"></i>{{project.name}}</p>
</div>
```

The component's data:

```
data: function(){
    return {
        projects: [...],
        selectedProjects: [],
    }
},
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would add a key `selected` on project objects.

The template will be like this

```
<div v-for="project in projects" class="project" :class="{selected: project.selected}" @click="select(project)">
    <p><i class="fa fa-folder"></i>{{project.name}}</p>
</div>
```

And add `select` event. If you need `selectedProjects` array for some reason, you can have a computed function rather than having two arrays in data.

```
methods: {
    select(project) {
        project.selected = true
    }
},
computed: {
    selectedProjects () {
        return this.projects.filter(project => project.selected)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You got the right idea going, just add a click handler and a $ref:

```
@click="onProjectClicked(project.id)" ref="`project${project.id}`"
```

And the methods implementation:

```
methods: {
  onProjectClicked(id) {
     this.selectedProjects.push(id)
     this.$refs[`project${id}`].$el.addClass('selected')
  }
}
```

Comment: I would recommend against using refs in this case

Comment: `this.$refs[\`project${id}\`]` is undefined when I run this.

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of Vue's dynamic class bindings to achieve this. Let's say that each of your projects has a property called `isSelected` (false by default). Then you can do the following ..

```
<div v-for="project in projects" class="project" :class="{selected: project.isSelected}" @click="handleClick(project)">
    <p><i class="fa fa-folder"></i>{{project.name}}</p>
</div>
```

Then in your script ..

```
  methods: {
    handleClick(project) {
      project.isSelected = !project.isSelected
      if (project.isSelected) {
        this.selectedProjects.push(project.id)
      } else {
        this.selectedProjects.splice(this.selectedProjects.indexOf(project.id), 1)
      }

    }
  }
```